# Bash if else statement error

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

```
for (( c=0; c<$i; c++ )); do
if [[ "$aTitle" == "${bookTitle[$c]}" ]]; then 
if [[ "$aAuthor" == "${author[$c]}" ]]; then    
found=true
fi
fi
done

echo $found
```

Hi, im pretty new to shell programming, can anyone tell me why I get this error when I run this block of codes? Thanks a lot.
bookTitle & author is an array of strings
aTitle & aAuthor is an input by user

```
function add_new_book
{
echo "1) add_new_book"

found=false

echo -n "Title: "
read aTitle
echo -n "Author: "
read aAuthor

for (( c=0; c<$i; c++ )); do
    if [[ "$aTitle" == "${bookTitle[$c]}" ]]; then 

        if [[ "$aAuthor" == "${author[$c]}" ]]; then    

            found=true

        fi

    fi
done

echo $found
}

#author[$i]=$aAut}

./menu.sh: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./menu.sh: line 43: `   done'
```

Comment: The error is likely elsewhere.

Comment: execute as bash -x ./menu.sh and post the output

Comment: I don;t see the problem, my sample is passed ok

Comment: what is line 43 from menu.sh and try with if [ "$aTitle" == "${booktitile[$c]}" ]; then similar for next if stmt

Comment: thanks for all the repies. I've uploaded the whole function Line 43 is the line "done"

Comment: elsewhere in the script, you may have an `if` with missing `fi`

Comment: your script works for me. I suspect you have an illegal character in your script, maybe a tab that is copy-and-pasted as 8 blanks. So you see the problem but we cannot reproduce. Can you tell us where you uploaded the script?

Answer (score 0):

your `for loop` is wrong for standard posix shell!
It's not C/C++, it's shell and here's the usual way to do it:

```
for c in $(seq 0 $i); do
    ...
done
```

and the following construct:

```
typeset -i i END
for ((i=0;i<END;++i)); do echo $i; done
```

is bash specific and the following gives no error:

```
#!/bin/bash

function add_new_book() {
    echo "1) add_new_book"

    found=false

    echo -n "Title: "
    read aTitle
    echo -n "Author: "
    read aAuthor

    # declare c and END as integers
    typeset -i c END
    let END=5 # use END instead of $i if $i is not defined!
    for ((c=0;c<i;++c)); do

        if [[ "$aTitle" == "${bookTitle[$c]}" ]]; then 

            if [[ "$aAuthor" == "${author[$c]}" ]]; then    

                found=true

            fi

        fi
    done

    echo $found
}

add_new_book
```

So I guess you may have been trying to run that example with `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` which may be another shell like `dash` or `bsh`. Also you shall not use `$i` in the for loop condition, but `i` withouth the `$`.

N.B.: in the script I'm giving, there still is an error: `$i` is not defined within the context of the script!

Comment: Given that he successfully uses the `function` keyword to define the function, I doubt he is using a strictly POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 0):

This example script might be help you more.

```
bookTitle="linux,c,c++,java"
author="dony,jhone,stuart,mohan"

function add_new_book()
{
    IFS=', ' 
    read -a bookTitle <<< "$bookTitle"
    read -a author <<< "$author"

    echo "1) add_new_book"

    found=false

    echo -n "Title: "
    read aTitle
    echo -n "Author: "
    read aAuthor


    for index in "${!bookTitle[@]}"
    do  
        if [[ "$aTitle" == "${bookTitle[index]}" ]]
        then    

            if [[ "$aAuthor" == "${author[index]}" ]]
            then    
                    found=true
            fi
        fi
    done

    echo $found
}
```